# Flutter / Amplify - A problem occurred configuring project ':amplify_analytics_pinpoint_android'

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

Can't run flutter app on emulator

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':amplify_analytics_pinpoint_android'.
> this and base files have different roots
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be nice to have a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so other users are able to answer your question.

Comment: hey did you get any solution?? i am also facing this issue ):

Comment: Hi yes,  by moving the file to C drive. SLR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the issue by Move the file from E Drive to C Drive